# XPath and Priority attribute with |

Tags: xpath

I have two XPaths:

1. `[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[contains(@href, '/PenSide')|//span[contains(text(), 'Side')]]")]`
2. `[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[contains(@id,'PenSide')]")]`

both these are tied to property SideIcon (`public IPageModelProperty SideIcon{ get; set; }`)

I would like to use Priority attribute on these two XPaths. However it's not currently working.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[contains(@href, '/PenSide')|//span[contains(text(), 'Side')]]", Priority = 1)]
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[contains(@id,'PenSide')]", Priority = 2)]
public IPageModelProperty SideIcon{ get; set; }
```

Comment: You've tagged this XPath, but that doesn't seem to be the key technology you are asking about. I don't recognize this `[FindsBy(How` syntax from any product/language I'm familiar with; if you want help from people who understand it, you need better tags on your question.